# Failed to open stream HTTP request failed - soap - getheader - file_get_contents

Tags: php, apache, curl, dns, file-get-contents

I use an api for parse a xml for ever 1 year with cronjob every 30 minutes, 
suddenly i found that I'm no longer able to connect to server.
with my test i get this error:

```
failed to open stream HTTP request failed
```

**what i did:**

```
contact to server provider -> they have no idea
ping to server -> works fine
check by file_get_contents('http://ip.xx/ and http://domian.xx') -> the same error
checked with curl -> still no success
check from localhost -> everything work fine
used get_headers() -> no luck
used gethostbyname('domain') -> successful returns ip
checked allow_url_fopen -> is 1
checked file_get_content through other random domains -> work
changed dns settings in resolve.conf from default to publick -> no luck
disabled directadmin csf -> nothing changed
```

a also used this code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(    
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true));

$header = explode("\n", curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);
```

it returns

```
    Array ( 
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
[1] => Date: Sun, 10 Aug 2014 08:42:07 GMT 
[2] => Server: Apache/2 
[3] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24 
[4] => Cache-Control: no-cache 
[5] => Pragma: no-cache 
[6] => Set-Cookie: irsp_admin_sessionhash=eb1aeff7a65ff9bfde01658804a56245; path=/; domain=.87.107.52.147 
[7] => Set-Cookie: irsp_user_sessionhash=b8878e85b41e47bbcf162c7a74a4f4f6; path=/; domain=.87.107.52.147 
[8] => Set-Cookie: irsp_invalidsignin=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.87.107.52.147
[9] => Vary: User-Agent 
[10] => Content-Type: text/html 
[11] => 
[12] => )
```

finally i have changed our server's ip address -> nothing changed (it changed from xxx.xx.xxx.48 to xxx.xx.xxx.49)

there is however a directory on that server which has a different job (http//ip**/api**) which i can connect to that normally

server info is:

Php 5.3.24
Apache 2.2.22

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there was something wrong with MTU . using ssh command below fixed the problem

```
ip link set dev venet0:0 mtu 1350
```